# Call a navigation method from another page - XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, navigation, nullreferenceexception

I'm making a Windows Store Application and I'm trying to create a header with some button that help the navigation between pages...

My problem is that I've created a *MasterPage.xaml* (that is used from every page so I don't need to copy and paste the style every time) and inside I've created some buttons and their click events.

```
private void HomePage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.HomePage));  
}
```

When I try to click the button from another page will occur a *NullReferenceException* and checking the value of *this.Frame* it says that it's *null*.

How can I use a navigation method called from another page?

I've tryed searching on the web but I'm not able to find something similar...

**EDIT**

In the *App.xaml.cs* I had to change some values for the purpose to make a MasterPage...

My code:

```
var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as MasterPage;
if (rootFrame == null)
{
   rootFrame = new MasterPage();
   if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
   {
      // TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
   }
   Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Surfing the web I've founded the solution.

Here the link to see how to use MasterPages and how to handle click from those pages:

http://loekvandenouweland.com/content/choosing-a-specific-master-page-for-each-windows-store-app-page

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the current frame is :

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

You should add this line of code in the constructor of your MasterPage, where "rootFrame" is a property of your page.

Comment: Still not working... _rootFrame_ is still _null_... Have I done something wrong?
I've added _private Frame rootFrame_ in the class; the _rootFrame = Window.Current.Current as Frame_ in the constructor

Comment: Window.Current.Current? It's "Content" and not "Current" to the end. In your App.xaml.cs you should have this line by default (in the "OnLaunched" event), if the frame is null it should initialize a Frame. Check if it is there.

Comment: Ya, it was Content, I'd just failed in the writing of the comment :D

For the purpose to make a MasterPage I had to change the App.xaml.cs changing the rootframe, I've made an EDIT with my code

Comment: Ok, this is your issue, you're setting a Page as Content of the Windows, so you don't have a Frame in your app. I think this is the wrong way for your purpose, why don't you create a User Control and use it in your pages?

Comment: I've find a way to do this, I'll close the question